# How do I add "from" in an email message using Amazon SES in PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

How do I add "from" in an email message using Amazon SES in PHP?

I can't find it in their SDK:

```
 * Keys for the $destination parameter:
 *  ToAddresses - _string_|_array_ (Optional) The To: field(s) of the message. Pass a string for a single value, or an indexed array for multiple values.
 *  CcAddresses - _string_|_array_ (Optional) The CC: field(s) of the message. Pass a string for a single value, or an indexed array for multiple values.
 *  BccAddresses - _string_|_array_ (Optional) The BCC: field(s) of the message. Pass a string for a single value, or an indexed array for multiple values.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonSES/send_email

The $source parameter is essentially the "From", if you mean "Reply-To" you can set that also within the $opt parameter.